# Deleted data missing in Clio API.Only created and Updated are available

Tags: clio-api

With Clio API, when a request is placed with created_since and updated_since, deleted information is not provided by Clio.

I have all the tasks saved in my DB from Clio.

Now I go to Clio and delete 2 Tasks

So, when I request for an update on the tasks using created_since and updated_since, I do not get the tasks that are deleted.

How do I get the deleted details from Clio API

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding your question, but why would you expect the tasks to be returned via API call if they have been deleted in Clio?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same need.

I am keeping a remote copy of the Clio database in constant sync in order to produce custom reports for clients.

When Contacts/Matters/Activities/Bills/etc are deleted, I would like to see that through an API call but at this point have to scan through my entire database and compare everything I received and manually figure out what to delete.

It is a time-consuming problem fraught with difficult problems.

+1